# how to prove the following formula true using semantic equivalences

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hi I am trying to prove the following the formula and this is what I have so far

```
false ∨ p ≡ p
```

This is what I have do so far

```
false ∨ p

(p ∧ ¬p) v p ≡ negation

¬p ∧ P ≡ absorbtion
```

This is where I am stuck, I do not know how to proceed forward

Comment: Isn't drawing a truth table a valid solving method (even though of the title)?

Comment: @JnxF unfortunately no, they want us to understand all methods of solving formulas not just truth tables

Comment: The Absorption equivalences are: $(A \vee B) \wedge A \equiv A, \; (A \wedge B) \vee A \equiv A $ So $$(p\wedge \neg p)\vee p \equiv \boxed{?}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:
\begin{align}
F\lor p &\equiv ¬¬(F\lor p)\tag{Double negation}\\
&\equiv \lnot(\lnot F \land \lnot p) \tag{DeMorgan's Rule}\\
&\equiv \lnot (T \land \lnot p) \tag{$\lnot F \equiv T$}\\
&\equiv \lnot (\lnot p) \tag{Tautology }\\
&\equiv p \tag{Double negation}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to proceed.  You need to take a step back and try again.

The Absorption equivalences are: $(A \vee B) \wedge A \equiv A, \; (A \wedge B) \vee A \equiv A $ So $$(p\wedge \neg p)\vee p \equiv \boxed{?}$$